# Drupal 7 views exposed filter shows up even when the user does not have access to the field

Tags: drupal-7, view

I have a view that shows user profile fields in a tabular format. There is a "Country" field, which is not accessible to anonymous users. When viewed as anonymous user, the field is not shown by Views, which is correct. However, I also have the same field exposed, so that users can filter by "Country". The exposed filter shows up for anonymous user and an anonymous user can actually filter by the field, even though he does not see the field value. Am I missing something or it is normal behavior? Is there a way to force the filter to be hidden for anonymous users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in fact is a known issue and detailed at http://drupal.org/node/1352654. As per the last comment in that issue this "wont fix". That's strange, and certainly not to my liking. Hopefully there will be some solution in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this without having to do any custom coding, you can try to display the filter as a block and set the permissions on the block to display only to authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks. I know, I can put the filter as a block, though not possible in the current use case. Anyway, I'll look into this further and see if already being discussed by the community on drupal.org. To me, this seems something that should work out of the box.